# I am getting NameError (undefined local variable or method `analytics' for AnalyticsDemo:Class): in my production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, analytics, sidekiq, web-worker

I am using `'analytics-ruby', '~> 2.0.0'` in my worker as:

```
class AnalyticDemo
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options unique: true

    def analytics
      @analytics ||= Segment::Analytics.new(
        write_key: Figaro.env.segment_write_key
      )
    end

    def perform(demo_id, demo_name)
      analytics.track(user_id: demo_id, event: demo_name)
      analytics.flush
    end
end
```

It's working on my local environment, but it's giving `NameError (undefined local variable or method analytics'` for AnalyticsDemo:Class)` on the production environment.

Comment: `analytics` is an instance method. You need an instance of `AnalyticsDemo`. To obtain one simple call `a_test = AnalyticsDemo.new` and then call `a_test.analytics`

Comment: What code specifically is triggering this error?